# Which version of Pip to use with my Python installs?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Being new to Python,  I'd love to clear up a few points that I couldn't get from reading various articles and tutorials.

After using Homebrew to install Python3, I noticed that it had installed both Python3 and Python3.4. I was also a little surprised that there are now three versions of pip on my machine too; pip, pip3 and pip3.4.

I created a new virtualenv and told it to use Python3, using the following command:

`virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 mysite`

I was also surprised that the version of Python that it installed in my VM was 3.4.

1. Is it safe to have these multiple version of Python and Pip hanging around on my machine?
2. Am I right to assume that I should take extra care to use the matching version of pip with Python, for example, pip3.4 with Python3.4?

Comment: python3 and python3.4 are likely the same; ditto for pip3 and pip3.4 Try `pip3 --version` and see what you get; it will likely tell which Python version it is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it is safe. Python uses this naming like python3.4, python3.5 etc to differentiate between releases. `python3` is a symbolic link to the current `python3.x` version. Pip follows the same convention.
2. If you're using `python3.4` explicitly, you should be using `pip3.4` specifically as well. Otherwise, just use `python3` and `pip3`. For Python 2, you can simply use `python` (which, unless you installed the Homebrew version as well), will be the system Python), and ditto for `pip`. `python2.7` and `pip2.7` may also work.

In general, to find out which Python version goes with which pip you're using, try:

```
pip --version
```

and you'll see the Python included in the result.

Answer (score 1):

No need to worried about if you have multiple version of Python and Pip installed. just check your version by writing in terminal :

**$ brew info python**

or to check the version of pip write in terminal :

**$ brew info pip**

and make sure you have updated your both pip and python version (write in terminal $ brew upgrade pip/python)

and other way to install python is go to https://www.python.org/downloads/  and choose as your requirement, there is two version available 2.7.9 & 3.4.3 , 
after installing python write in terminal $ **python -V** to check its version :) Hope it will help :)